# Orientdb GC overhead limit exceeded/out of memory error and slow performance

Tags: mysql, garbage-collection, orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

My orientdb database has around 2.3 million records. I'm trying to query all duplicate records (there are around 750,000 of them) using statement-
`SELECT FROM (select PROP1, PROP2, count(*) as c from vin_data group by PROP1 ) where c > 1`. When I set the limit to around 200, It takes around 180s to query (which I believe is slow). But when I set the limit to 750000, it gives me Out of memory error. My ram is 4GB and I have set Xms64m and Xmx3600m. I have set index on PROP1 and PROP1+PROP2(composite). My question is- Is 4GB ram enough for a 2.3 million record database?

Answer (score 2):

For the query above both indexes are worthless, because they are not used in the `GROUP BY`. Without any "where" condition, the entire class is scanned. You could try optimizing it by adding the `PARALLEL` keyword at the end of the statement. If you have multiple cores it should be much faster.

Anyway, with the upcoming release v3.0 (still in pre-alpha) a lot of effort has been put in the new SQL engine and queries like yours should be much faster.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the response. I indexed my class for different purpose though. So, 2.3 million records taking up 4GB ram is normal considering the kind of query? My purpose for now is to remove duplicates from my database. Any trick you might suggest that could speed up my query?

Comment: By the way, I executed the query on a system with 24 GB ram, allocating 20GB for Xmx, parallelizing on 8 cores and SSD (if that matters). I still get GC overhead limit exceeded. I'm pretty sure this is not normal. Any suggestions for troubleshooting? and when will v3.0 be released?

Comment: Unfortunately `group by` and `order by` work in RAM. How many records in the final result set have more than 1 record grouped? Could you execute this `SELECT count(*) FROM (select PROP1, PROP2, count(*) as c from vin_data group by PROP1 ) where c > 1`?

Comment: the result is 501417